# 2 columns running total in access

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am developing an small access database to track my stock. I have two columns (In and Out). I would like to create a running total in a query and report to show the +- balance when a stock is received or item leaves the stock.

Example:

```
Stock ID     Opening     Date                 In       Out        RunTot
1              500       1/2/2019             60       0            30
3              200       1/10/2019            40       0            70
1                        1/30/2019            0        5            65
```

Up to now, I have tried couple of codes but not producing the result I need.

```
RunTot: DSum("[QtyIn] + [Opening] - [QtyOut]","tblTransaction","[StockID] <= " & [StockID])
```

Your assistance will be highly appreciated.
Thanks,
Oscar

Comment: Opening seems to be`Null`for`StockID`3. The fields have to be unnulled: `DSum("Nz([QtyIn],0) + Nz([Opening],0) - Nz([QtyOut],0)", ...`

Comment: @zanerok - thanks for your suggestion. I have indicated the following code but I am getting a feedback of not entering an operator. RunTot: Dsum("Nz([QtyIn],0)+Nz([BStock],0)-Nz([QtyOut],0),"[tblTransaction]","[StockID] <= " & [StockID])

Comment: Dquote missing! `Dsum("Nz([QtyIn],0)+Nz([BStock],0)-Nz([QtyOut],0)` **"** `,"[tblTransaction]","[StockID] <= " & [StockID])`

Comment: Thanks again Zanerok, the code DSum("Nz([QtyIn],0)+Nz([BStock],0)-Nz([QtyOut],0) ","[tblTransaction]","[StockID] <= " & [tblTransaction].[StockID]) is summing up values in the column [QtyIn]+[BStock] and subtracting the sum values from column [QtyOut] which is not what I need.  This code (SELECT SUM([QtyIn]-[QtyOut]) FROM [tblTransaction] t WHERE t.[TransDate]<=  [tblTransaction].[TransDate] AND t.StockID = [tblTransaction].StockID) is doing the subtractions with the runtot correctly, the only problem is when I add the [BStock] to the [QtyIn], the running total is doubling the [BStock].

Comment: @ zanerok: sorry I am new on here but is there a way to send a screenshot or a demo of my database?